# Are Posix I/O operations on filenames sequentially coherent?

Tags: c, io, posix, read-write

I would like to know whether there is a Posix standard guarantee that modifications to a file are guaranteed to be visible through repeated `open`/`close` calls on the same file name. For exposition, consider this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$(mktemp)

echo "Some data" >> $FILE
cat $FILE
```

Is it guaranteed that by the time `echo` finishes, all data is available in the file?

In terms of Posix functions, an example could be like this:

```
const char fn[] = "/tmp/somefile";
const char data[] = "hello world";

// Stage 1
{
   int fd = open(fn, O_CREAT);
   write(fd, data, sizeof data); // #1
   close(fd);
}

// Stage 2
{
   int fd = open(fn);
   read(fd, ...);                // #2
   close(fd);
}
```

Is it guaranteed that the write at line #1 is visible to the read #2, or could the OS cache the write so that it does not propagate in time? We can assume that no other process knows the file name or otherwise subverts the file lookup.

Comment: From the Linux [close(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) man page: Not checking the return value of close() is a common but nevertheless serious programming error. It is quite possible that errors on a previous write(2) operation are first reported at the final close(). Not checking the return value when closing the file may lead to silent loss of data.

Comment: @LucaMartini: How would this affect the Bash script? Can one check that the pipe operation succeeds? Also, does successful return of `close` guarantee coherence?

Comment: I was referring to the example and not to the script. Maybe one can also check the return value of the `echo "Some data" >> $FILE`. I've found no clues in the POSIX standard apart from the fflush call that is also present in the C standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. E.g. from the write() specification ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html ):

```
After a write() to a regular file has successfully returned:

    Any successful read() from each byte position in the file that was modified by that write shall return the data specified by the write() for that position until such byte positions are again modified.

    Any subsequent successful write() to the same byte position in the file shall overwrite that file data.
```

Note that it says "Any" read(), i.e. you can open() a new fd and read() via that, and those same guarantees are provided.

Incidentally, while this kind of strong consistency makes it easy to reason about the semantics, it also makes providing a POSIX compliant distributed FS with decent performance very difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: So for example, would Linux be strictly Posix compliant in this regard?

Comment: @KerrekSB: AFAIK, for "normal" local filesystems, yes. Networked/distributed/clustered/whatever FS'es do often take shortcuts in the name of performance, though this shouldn't really be seen within a single client, only as incoherence across clients.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Imagine an application doing `write()` and then `read()` at the same file offset. If `read()` doesn't return data just written, that would be a completely broken kernel, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: If we're talking about one single file descriptor, then I agree entirely. But I'm asking about two potentially completely unrelated stages. Do you have any guarantees about that?

Comment: @KerrekSB: this behaviour is required by POSIX. Linux `man write(2)` says: _POSIX requires that a read(2) which can be proved to occur after a write() has returned returns the new data. Note that not all file systems are POSIX conforming._

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: OK, that's cool. What about real file systems then - is ext3fs Posix compliant? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, all of ext[2,3,4]fs are POSIX compliant, as are XFS and btrfs, and others. Bugs are of course possible, though.